# <apa7> Why is professor, course, and duedate not appearing on the title page?

Tags: latex, tex

I am using the LaTeX package apa7 to format my research paper. However, the professor, course, and duedate for the assignment is not appearing in the title when the \maketitle command is called while my name and affiliation appears just fine. I don't see any references to this problem on the Internet for some reason, what is the issue?

```
\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title{Natural Language Processing With GPT3:\\ More than just a cheating tool}
\shorttitle{More than just a cheating tool}
\author{Anish Goyal}
\affiliation{GSMST}
\course{American Literature and Composition}
\professor{Susan Kohanek}
\duedate{January 31, 2023}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}}
\setlength\parindent{36pt}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I tried looking at the apa7 manual. I expect the course, professor, and duedate to appear on the title page as indicated on the apa formatting guide. Instead, only my name and affiliation appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is displayed if you use the student paper document mode instead of the manuscript mode:

```
\documentclass[stu,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title{Natural Language Processing With GPT3:\\ More than just a cheating tool}
\shorttitle{More than just a cheating tool}
\author{Anish Goyal}
\affiliation{GSMST}
\course{American Literature and Composition}
\professor{Susan Kohanek}
\duedate{January 31, 2023}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.25mm}}
\setlength\parindent{36pt}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```